# Creating a PEM file from javascript looks different from Java causing a failed signature verification

Tags: node.js, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature, pem

I'm trying to verify a SHA1 with RSA signature with its public key, I have written the java code below which works perfectly but but javascript cannot verify when it uses same modulus and exponent which is created by crypto or ursa. though If i use it against the pem file created by java it works.
any idea or suggestion of the best way of converting the java code to javascript?

JAVA:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;
public class Verify {
static public Boolean verifySignature(String modulus, String exponent , String encodedMsg, String encodedSignature, String signatureAlgorithm)
        throws Exception {

    try {
        RSAPublicKeySpec senderPublicKeySpec =
                new RSAPublicKeySpec(
                        new BigInteger(modulus, 16),
                        new BigInteger(exponent, 16)
                );

        RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) KeyFactory.getInstance(Constants.RSA_KEY).generatePublic(senderPublicKeySpec);

        System.out.println("------------ pem file ----------------");
        System.out.println("format:" +  rsaPublicKey.getFormat());//x.509
        byte[] data = rsaPublicKey.getEncoded();
        rsaPublicKey.getFormat();
        String base64encoded = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(data));
        System.out.println(base64encoded);
        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        signature.initVerify(rsaPublicKey);
        signature.update(encodedMsg.getBytes());

 //this returns true;
        return signature.verify(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedSignature.getBytes()));

    } catch (Exception invaKeySpeExp) {
        throw new Exception(invaKeySpeExp.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
'use strict';

var ursa = require('ursa');

function verifySignature( modulus,  exponent,  encodedMsg) {
var pem = fs.readFileSync('./java.pem');
var publicKeyNode = ursa.createPublicKeyFromComponents(new Buffer(modulus,'binary'), new Buffer(exponent,'binary'));
var publicKeyJava = ursa.createPublicKey(pem);

var sig = ursa.createVerifier(signatureAlgorithm);
sig.update(encodedMsg);
var successJ = sig.verify(publicKeyJava , new Buffer(encodedSignature, 'base64'), 'base64');
console.log(successJ);


var successN = sig.verify(publicKeyNode , new Buffer(encodedSignature, 'base64'), 'base64');
console.log(successN);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
true  //from verifying against PEM file created by Java
crypto.js:126 //from Verifying against modulus and exponent
return this._handle.digest(outputEncoding);
                  ^
Error: Not initialized
at Error (native)
at Hash.digest (crypto.js:126:23)
at Object.verify (/Users/aemami/WebstormProjects/temp/node_modules/ursa/lib/ursa.js:705:39)
at verifySignature (/Users/aemami/WebstormProjects/temp/index.js:28:22)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/aemami/WebstormProjects/temp/index.js:64:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

Comment: Please include all the parameters to your function `verifySignature`.

Comment: "This function is similar to crypto.createVerify(), except this function takes a hash algorithm name (e.g., "sha256") and not a crypto+hash name combination (e.g., "RSA-SHA256")." Could you try just `SHA1` as identifier in `createVerifier`? (Horrid API by the way).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, thanks maarten, that got me one step closer. I created a pem file from the Java and I can verify it in javascript. Basically the java PEM (x.509 format) looks different from what javascript is creating. I will update the question to reflect the problem!

Comment: `new Buffer(modulus,'binary')` -> how did you convert to / from this binary value? Or how did you retrieve it? Could you print out the exponent in decimals or hexadecimals?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, just figured out - it seems like an odd behavior ursa.createPublicKeyFromComponents(new Buffer(modulus,'hex'), new Buffer(exponent,'hex'));  - the second parameter HAS TO BE binary but in hex format in this case the exponent has to be set to 010011  (10011) would not work!

Comment: @nightograph It's converted to bytes first by the library, so that's not too surprising. Note that you probably mean `010001` (the fourth number of Fermat, a prime with just two bits set) not `010011`, which is not a prime.